# Is it possible "disable-web-security" on Chrome for only selected web sites?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

When you hit the bloody pre-flight error ( at those XHR requests during your development), the recommended solution is this:

```
open -a Google\ Chrome --args --disable-web-security --user-data-dir
```

Well, I do not want that do this cause Chrome is my default browser for browsing the Net and my development will last 4-5 months for that proj and I do not want to turn that on/off on a daily basis. It's just not gonna happen.

Then it makes you want to ask whether there is an option or a way to tell Hey Charlie! `Turn off the web security but only, and only if you are XHR'ing to this domain`!.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000** in header which will only allow urls that you mention in headers but in every call you have extra header payload for urls.

You can see more details  on https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/jvaneyck.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/cross-domain-requests-in-javascript/amp/